# Apostrophe-pieces-pages can't register page type

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

I try to create a new pieces page, kind of a blog style in apostrophe cms. I have `trainings`, `trainings-widgets` and `trainings-pages` folders. I registered them all in `app.js`; pieces by themselves and widgets work beautifully. The problem is when I try to add page of Trainings type. I get `Error: template not found: pages/trainings-page.html` in console.

In `apostrophe-pages/index.js` I have it configured:

```
module.exports = {
    types: [{
            name: 'home',
            label: 'Home'
        },
        {
            name: 'trainings-page',
            label: 'Trainings'
        }
    ]
}
```

And in `trainings-pages/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'trainings-page',
    label: 'Training Page',
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
    piecesFilters: []
}
```

I can't figure out what might be wrong here.

Edit: A showcase git:
https://github.com/msdsk/apostrophe-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the module directory name being incorrect, as noted:

`lib/modules/trainigs-pages` should be:

`lib/modules/trainings-pages`

When we fix this we graduate to a new error:

`Error: template not found: trainings-pages:layout.html`

You are extending `layout.html`. But that file is in a different module, `apostrophe-pages`, that `trainings-pages` does not extend, and so it is never found. This is our fault for not recommending a more universal location for `layout.html` in the tutorial.

You can solve it two ways:

OPTION ONE

1. Move `layout.html` to `lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/views/layout.html`.
2. Always `extend` it like this:

`{% extends 'apostrophe-templates:layout.html' %}`

This "cross-module" path syntax will find it in the `apostrophe-templates` module no matter what module you're in.

OPTION TWO

Another option is to set the `viewsFolderFallback` option of `apostrophe-templates` in `app.js`, like this:

```
'apostrophe-templates': { 
  viewsFolderFallback: __dirname + '/views'
},
```

And create a `views/` folder at the top level of the project and move `layout.html` there. Then you don't have to use the special syntax, you can just write `layout.html` and if the module doesn't have its own, it'll look in the fallback folder. This is what we usually do in-house.

I'll discuss with the rest of the Apostrophe core team whether the tutorial should recommend option one or option two, and adjust the apostrophe CLI to set up option two automatically if that is preferred.

(There is a third option: you can put things in `lib/modules/apostrophe-module/views` and it works as a fallback without any configuration. That's because all modules eventually inherit from `apostrophe-module`. But our feeling in the past has been that this approach is not very intuitive.)

Comment: Thank you! You're great, incredibly helpful and Apostrophe is absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo error on your module directory's name : `lib/modules/trainigs-pages` should be `lib/modules/training-pages`

Comment: I fixed the typo but it didn't change anything, I'm afraid - unless there's something more to it.